# Jquery Script Overruling my @Html.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I have written some code which is suppose to POST values to the controller using Ajax and @Html.BeginForm.

But it seems that my Ajax is overruling my @Html.BeginForm submit so the model properties are not being populated.

**View**

```
<script>
    $(document)
        .on("click",
            ".submit",
            function(e) {
                var val = $(".Date").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/EventSubmission/Submit',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "dateTime": val })
                });
            });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "EventSubmission"))
{
    <h3>Your contact details</h3>

    <h5>Name</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Name);

    <h5>Email address</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Phone);

    <h5>Phone number</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Email);  

    <h5> Date and time of event:</h5>
    <input type="date" id="Date" class="Date"/> <input type="time" id="Time" />    

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"/>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(Event ev, DateTime dateTime)
{
    ev.DateOfEvent = dateTime;

        string text = "<html> <head> </head>" +
        " <body style= \" font-size:14px; font-family: Arial\">" +
        "<b>Contact Information</b> <br>" + 
        "Name: " + ev.Arranger.Contact_Name + "<br>" +
        "Email: " + ev.Arranger.Contact_Email + "<br>" +
        "Phone: " + ev.Arranger.Contact_Phone + "<br>" +
        "<b>Company Details</b> <br>" +
        "Name: " + ev.Company.CompanyName + "<br>" +
        "Size: " + ev.Company.CompanySize + "<br>" +
        "Website: " + ev.Company.CompanyWebsite + "<br>" +
        "<b>Event Type</b> <br>" +
        ev.Type + "<br>" +
        "<b>Event Details</b> <br>" +
        "Name: " + ev.Name + "<br>" +
        "Address: " + ev.Location.Address + "<br>" +
        "Postcode: " + ev.Location.Postcode + "<br>" +
        "Local MP Attending?: " + ev.LocalMpName + "<br>" +
        "Open to Media?: " + ev.EventMedia + "<br>" +
        "Open to Public: " + ev.OpenToPublic + "<br>" +
        "Date and Time: " + ev.DateOfEvent + "<br>" +
        "Description: " + ev.Description + "<br>" +
        "Estemated Antendance: " + ev.Attendees + "<br>" +
        "Show on Evnt Map: " + ev.ShowOnWebsite +

        "</body></html>";

        SendEmail("rubidgetest1@gmail.com", text);
        Event tempForm = new Event();
        return View(tempForm);
}
```

This currently isnt working because the model properties are not being populated, the only one being populated is the ev.DateOfEvent and I'm guessing this is because the Ajax is the only thing posting to the contoller.

**So basically I want the Ajax and @Html.BeginForm() to post to the controller**

Comment: What is the point of the ajax call? (and your making both the normal submit and the ajax call - the ajax call sends only a value for `dateTime` and the normal submit sends all the values of the successful form controls in the request - your calling the method twice)

Comment: I need to set the type of the input field for the date as a "DateTime". I didnt know how to do this using the @Html helpers, which then meant I wasnt able to pass it to the model using the form, like I did with all the other fields. I have now found a way I doing this by using this code instead of using AJAX `@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Date, new { @type = "date"});` `@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Time, new { @type = "time"});` I just made two separate fields then combined them together in my controller

 It would still be great to know if it was possible to do it using AJAX.

Comment: But what is the point of using ajax? (and `type="date"` and `type="time"` has only limited browser support - not supported at all in FireFox for example, so I suggest you consider a jquery datetimepicker plugin)

Comment: @StephenMuecke The ajax is so I can send the datetime value to the contoller thats it?

Comment: But the normal submit also sends it. Just give the inputs a `name` attribute and include matching parameters in your POST method and the values will be bound.